# Local print from browser without the print dialog

Tags: java, browser, printing, dialog, kiosk

We have a jsp that will be referenced from a kiosk. We need to print to a receipt printer attached to the kiosk. Customer will press a button and we will print a barcode. No dialog ... no hassle (hopefully).

How could this be done? I am guessing we will need to use a client-side script of some sort. Can we access local com ports from javascript?

The kiosk will be running some form of Windows. We do have control over what is installed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only print on systems that are available on the server side or by manipulating client side program (Browser Plugin).

Possible solutions include:

1. Don't use JSP, use a Program instead.
2. Have the Server in the same LAN and the Printer available to the server.
3. Firefox Plugin JS Print Setup

(You could of course change the code of the browser, but I doubt you want that.)

Comment: Are you saying I can't even write a string to a COM port?

Comment: No, of course not. The Page inside a browser may not interfere with the hardware. (You know, for security reasons)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes, I'm surprised but there is a plugin that does that. I've added it to my solutions list.

Comment: Thank you! You have restored my faith in the <strike>sanity of the</strike> IT industry. The FF `JS Print` technique works. Are there any other options? Ones that work with Safari? Chrome? IE?

Comment: Most likely there are plugins for them as well (The FF Plugin mentions Active X for IE if I remember correctly). I'm sure you'll find them if you enter '<Browser> Plugin Print' into your favorite search engine.